# How to avoid NaN in an e function?

Tags: r, optimization, nan, exp

I am trying to solve these equations for q1 and q2. However, the output is giving me "NaN". Does anyone have an idea how to avoid those?

```
k2<-2
k1<-2
a<- 20
b<- -0.03
w <- 1.1

model <- function(q) {
pi1 <- -exp(-a*(w*(100*q[1]-0.5*q[1]^2-0.5*q[1]*q[2])-k1)*(-a*(w*(100-q[1]-0.5*q[2])-k1)))
pi2 <- -exp(-a*(w*(100*q[2]-0.5*q[2]^2-0.5*q[1]*q[2])-k2)*(-a*(w*(100-q[2]-0.5*q[1])-k2)))
c(pi1 = pi1, pi2 = pi2)
}

ss1 <- rootSolve::multiroot(f = model, start = c(1, 1))
ss1
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your `model` with initial guess of `c(1,1)` for `q` plus constants has you trying to calculate `exp(4547526)` in `pi1` and `pi2`.  So `model(c(1,1))` gives you `-Inf`.

Comment: A good rule to follow:  before attempting to root-solve (or any kind of optimization) an equation, first graph it so you know what sort of initial 'guess' parameters make sense.

Comment: I tried this model with a different utility function and the value should be s.th around 3, so the initial guess is not that bad, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find the roots with the following code :

```
model <- function(q, bool_Print = FALSE) 
{
  k2 <- 2
  k1 <- 2
  a <- 20
  b <- -0.03
  w <- 1.1
  pi1 <- exp( -a * (w * (100 * q[1] - 0.5 * q[1] ^ 2 - 0.5 * q[1] * q[2]) - k1) * (-a * (w * (100 - q[1] - 0.5 * q[2]) - k1)))
  pi2 <- exp( -a * (w * (100 * q[2] - 0.5 *q[2] ^2 - 0.5 * q[1] * q[2]) - k2) * (-a * (w * (100 - q[2] - 0.5 * q[1]) - k2)))
  val <- pi1 ^ 2 + pi2 ^ 2
  names(val) <- NULL
  
  if(bool_Print == TRUE)
  {
    print("pi1")
    print(pi1)
    print("pi2")
    print(pi2)
    print("Val")
  }
  
  if(is.na(val) | is.nan(val) | is.infinite(val))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
   return(val) 
  }
}

library(DEoptim)
obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = model, lower = rep(-1000, 2), upper = rep(1000, 2))

model(q = obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem, bool_Print = TRUE) 

[1] "pi1"
par1 
   0 
[1] "pi2"
par2 
   0 
[1] "Val"
[1] 0
```